# CMS with review, approval and revision

Tags: php, cms

I am looking for a content management system, which needs to have a very specific workflow.

Whenever someone wants to make a change to an article (and there will be thousands of articles) the user can suggest changes. After changes are suggested a group of users have to vote on changes. Some of the articles are very long, and may have multiple suggested changes going at the same time, so ability to git-like merge approved suggestions is highly desirable.

Must have functionality:

1. Ability to suggest changes
2. Ability to have a group of people vote on changes
3. Ability to show changes between versions by word (preferable) or by sentence
4. Ability to create multiple suggestions, and then merge them together (kind of like git)
5. Ability to assign different groups for different types of content
6. PDF export

If possible, a PHP based solution is ideal. Enterprise software with price tags is also an option as long as there is a trial that we can experiment with.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays we are in the process of decision making for a similar CMS. I can report you my findings.

I'm evaluating [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) at the moment and guess that we are going to choose it but it's not decided yet. The only downside with Confluence is that our need for a document approval workflow is only provided with some add-ons on the server model of Confluence. Right now we are evaluating the cloud model of Confluence. These add-ons are the [Comalatech Workflows](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.comalatech.workflow/server/overview) and a bunch of add-ons by [K15t](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/vendors/7016).

My second choice was [Excosoft](http://excosoft.com/) but I haven't found the opportunity to try their system yet and they don't seem to have a demo version. Theirs seem to be more suited to my technical documentation needs but lacks the features like general documentation, an inplace integration with a task tracking system (Confluence is integrated with Jira) and wiki features (even if they have them at least it isn't clearly stated on their website).

Comment: we ended up using sharepoint, and building a php script that ingests sharepoint's data for displaying articles. However, Confluence made it a lot easier for us to realize what users really wanted. We might be needing another CMS for other stuff very soon which will not need to integrate with outlook emails, and do a bunch of microsoft only things. Which CMS did you end up going with and what is your opinion on it so far?

Comment: @Dimi Unfortunately I'm fighting for a hopeless cause at our company :) We still didn't choose a certain path and everything is still in development hell. I'm trying to insist on using Confluence integrated with Jira but missing out the Comalatech Workflows add-on because it's still not being offered on the cloud. We recently did start using Google for Business and I've also started creating documents on Google Drive. Google Sheets and Docs have some interesting CMS-like add-ons which I'm going to explore in near future because I did like the way Google operates in general.